# Jest/Ionic 4 beta - import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular'; gets SyntaxError: Unexpected token export in Jest testing, not Ionic

Tags: angular, jestjs, ionic-native, ionic4

When running Jest against the base package, I get an error in Jest in running the test, which does not appear when simply running `ionic serve`.  Jest gets an error on

```
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
```

which is:

```
export { IonicModule } from './ionic-module';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

  3 | import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
  4 |
> 5 | import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
    | ^
  6 | import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
  7 | import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';
  8 |

  at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/script_transformer.js:403:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/app/app.component.spec.ts:5:1)
```

My Jest.config.json

```
module.exports = {
    collectCoverage: true,
    collectCoverageFrom: [
        "src/**/*.ts"
    ],
    coverageDirectory: "<rootDir>/coverage/",
    moduleNameMapper: {
        "@core/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/app/core/$1",
        "@state/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/app/state/$1"
    },
    preset: "jest-preset-angular",
    roots: ['src'],
    setupTestFrameworkScriptFile: "<rootDir>/src/setup-jest.ts",
    transformIgnorePatterns: [
        "node_modules/(?!(@ionic-native|@ionic|angularfire2)/)"
    ],
    verbose: false  
}
```

I am just using the sample side menu template and adjusting the components to run Jest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seeing all answers being quite long I have decided to give show what worked for me after reading [Jest unit testing no longer works with Ionic 4](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/15695).

To make it work you need to add to `jest.config.ts`:

```js
transformIgnorePatterns: [
  "node_modules/(?!@ionic-native|@ionic)"
],
```

And in `tsconfig.spec.json` set:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "allowJs": true,
},
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue appears when some file needs to be preprocessed before it can be used in Jest. In this case the ionic imports needs to be preprocessed but normally is ignored via the `transformIgnorePatterns`. But this is half the issue. We also need to add some babel to process the files so that they can run.

I was able to solve this issue by adding a .babelrc file with the following config

```
{ 
     "presets": [["@babel/preset-env", {
        "modules": "commonjs",
        "targets": {
          "node": "current"
        }
      }]],
      "plugins": ["transform-export-extensions", "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"]
}
```

I used the following jest config

```
{
    "jest": {
        "preset": "jest-preset-angular",
        "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>/src/setup-jest.ts",
        "globals": {
        "ts-jest": {
            "tsConfigFile": "tsconfig.jest.json",
            "useBabelrc": true
        },
        "__TRANSFORM_HTML__": true
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!@ngrx|angular2-ui-switch|ng-dynamic|@ionic|@ionic-native)"
    ],
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ]
  }
}
```

The src/tsconfig.spec.json also needed some minor adjustment.

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/spec",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "allowJs": true,
    "types": [
      "jest",
      "jquery",
      "jsdom",
      "node"
    ]
  }, 
  "include": [
    "polyfills.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your answer didn't work for me. However, I noticed that removing the extra parenthesis got rid of the error.  Try changing:

```
transformIgnorePatterns: [
    "node_modules/(?!(@ionic-native|@ionic|angularfire2)/)"
],
```

to

```
transformIgnorePatterns: [
    "node_modules/(?!@ionic-native|@ionic|angularfire2)"
],
```

For me, though, this now brings a new error:

```
Cannot find module '@ionic/core/loader' from 'app-initialize.js'
  at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:221:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@ionic/angular/dist/app-initialize.js:1:1)
```

This was all working fine until I upgraded to Ionic 4 beta 11 (from beta 8). I am also now using Jest 23.6.0 but it fails in Jest 23.5.0 as well.

I get these errors with or without your `babelrc` config.

For reference, here is my `ionic info`:

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)          : 4.1.2
   Ionic Framework            : @ionic/angular 4.0.0-beta.11
   @angular-devkit/core       : 0.8.3
   @angular-devkit/schematics : 0.8.3
   @angular/cli               : 6.2.3
   @ionic/ng-toolkit          : 1.0.7
   @ionic/schematics-angular  : 1.0.6

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0
   Cordova Platforms     : none
   Cordova Plugins       : no whitelisted plugins (0 plugins total)

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/Users/rc101077/Library/Android/sdk)
   ios-deploy        : 2.0.0
   ios-sim           : 7.0.0
   NodeJS            : v8.11.4 (/Users/rc101077/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.4/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.4.1
   OS                : macOS High Sierra
   Xcode             : Xcode 9.4.1 Build version 9F2000
```

Comment: From lots of configuration testing, this looks to be broken between `"@ionic/angular": "4.0.0-beta.8"` and `""@ionic/angular": "4.0.0-beta.9"`.

I've opened a bug with Ionic at: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/15695

Answer (score 1):

In my case, with Ionic 5, Angular 10 and NX monorepo, I had to do the following to enable Jest testing of an Ionic app.

*Note: Skip the first 4 steps if you already have standard Jest setup.*

*Note 2: The order of steps doesn't really matter.*

**1. Delete all Karma and Jasmine files and dependencies**

- Delete `karma.conf.js` and `src/test.ts`.
- Delete everything related to `karma` and `jasmine` from `package.json` (e.g. `@types/jasmine`, `karma` etc.)

**2. Add Jest dependencies**

Add `jest`, `jest-preset-angular`, `@types/jest` and `ts-jest` to your `devDependencies`, if you don't have them yet:

```sh
# if you use yarn:
yarn add --dev jest jest-preset-angular @types/jest ts-jest
# or if you use npm:
npm install --save-dev jest jest-preset-angular @types/jest ts-jest
```

**3. Update angular.json**

Update your `angular.json` file. Replace `architect` -> `test` configurations for Karma with configurations for Jest:

```json
"test": {
  "builder": "@nrwl/jest:jest",
  "options": {
    "jestConfig": "apps/my-app/jest.config.js",
    "polyfills": "apps/my-app/src/polyfills.ts"
  }
}
```

*Note: I use `@nrwl/jest:jest` builder. If you aren't using NX monorepo, just specify `@angular-builders/jest:run` as a builder, and remove "apps/my-app/" from the config options.*

**4. Create test-setup.ts**

Create `src/test-setup.ts` file with a single line content:

```js
import 'jest-preset-angular';
```

**5. Add Babel dependencies**

Add `babel-jest`, `@babel/preset-env` and `@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import` to your `devDependencies`:

```sh
# if you use yarn:
yarn add --dev babel-jest @babel/preset-env @babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import
# or if you use npm:
npm install --save-dev babel-jest @babel/preset-env @babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import
```

**6. Update tsconfig.spec.json**

Add `"allowJs": true` and `types` to the `compilerOptions` in your TypeScript config. Add `files` to compile `test-setup.ts` file created earlier.

My final version of `tsconfig.spec.json`:

```json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "../../dist/out-tsc",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "types": ["jest", "node"]
  },
  "files": ["src/test-setup.ts"],
  "include": ["src/**/*.spec.ts", "src/**/*.d.ts"]
}
```

**7. Create or update jest.config.js**

Create `jest.config.js` in your app root (where you have `package.json`), if you haven't yet.

*Note: I added `transformIgnorePatterns` and `global.ts-jest.babelConfig` settings to the default version of Jest config for Angular.*

The final version of the file looks like this:

```js
const esModules = ['@ionic'].join('|');

module.exports = {
  preset: '../../jest.preset.js',
  coverageDirectory: '../../coverage/apps/mobile-ui',
  snapshotSerializers: [
    'jest-preset-angular/build/AngularNoNgAttributesSnapshotSerializer.js',
    'jest-preset-angular/build/AngularSnapshotSerializer.js',
    'jest-preset-angular/build/HTMLCommentSerializer.js',
  ],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/src/test-setup.ts'], // leave `<rootDir>` string as is
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      babelConfig: {
        presets: [
          [
            '@babel/preset-env',
            { targets: { node: true }, modules: 'commonjs' }
          ]
        ],
        plugins: ['@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import']
      },
      tsConfig: '<rootDir>/tsconfig.spec.json',
      stringifyContentPathRegex: '\\.(html|svg)$',
      astTransformers: {
        before: [
          'jest-preset-angular/build/InlineFilesTransformer',
          'jest-preset-angular/build/StripStylesTransformer',
        ]
      },
    },
  },
  // To transform Ionic modules to UMD, because Jest can't import them otherwise
  // (see here: https://medium.com/@gregor.woiwode/how-to-setup-jest-in-an-ionic-4-project-ff1e5b72dd79)
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    `/node_modules/(?!${esModules})`
  ],
  displayName: 'my-app',
};
```

**Kudos** to this article which helped me with identifying these steps: [How to setup Jest in an Ionic 4 project | Gregor Woiwode | Apr 25, 2019 | Medium](https://medium.com/@gregor.woiwode/how-to-setup-jest-in-an-ionic-4-project-ff1e5b72dd79)